# Why this regex doesn't match the groups correctly in javascript implementations?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this case:

I need match the href links in the `<a></a>` elements. 
MY regex for this it's `<a href="([^"]*)"`

Check it working in here --> https://regex101.com/r/tB1hJ0/1

The problem is when i try to use this regex in javascript.

If I try using the implementations i dont get the same result:

```
var input = '2\
<p><a href="http://www.quackit.com/html/tutorial/html_links.cfm">Example Link</a></p>\
<div class="more-info"><a href="http://www.quackit.com/html/examples/html_links_examples.cfm">More Link Examples...</a></div>';

console.log((/<a href="([^"]*)"/gmi).exec(input)); //["<a href="http://www.quackit.com/html/tutorial/html_links.cfm"", "http://www.quackit.com/html/tutorial/html_links.cfm",
console.log(input.match(/<a href="([^"]*)"/gmi)); //["<a href="http://www.quackit.com/html/tutorial/html_links.cfm"", "<a href="http://www.quackit.com/html/examples/html_links_examples.cfm""]
```

**What  i am doing wrong?**

Comment: I don't see anything wrong..what exactly you want to capture??

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the capture group, not the matching text.

```js
var re = /<a href="([^"]*)"/gm; 
var str = '2\n<p><a href="http://www.quackit.com/html/tutorial/html_links.cfm">Example Link</a></p>\n<div class="more-info"><a href="http://www.quackit.com/html/examples/html_links_examples.cfm">More Link Examples...</a></div>';
match = re.exec(str);
while (match != null) {
  console.log("Matching text:"+match[0]) 
  console.log("Matching group:"+match[1]);//You need this
  match = re.exec(str);
}
```

Comment: oh, this works, but i don't undestand this behaviour. In another times I with deal with multiple matches like this `console.log("1m .... .22wwdhdhd  44dadaa 2".match(/(\d+)[a-z]+/gmi));` and the captoured groups works fine.

Answer (score 0):

you need this for the entire regex match

```js
/<a href="([^"]*)"/gm
```

Comment: Alexis answer is basically just mine sent later.